# $f,g$ coprime does not imply $V(f,g)$ empty

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There is something in this argument that is wrong but I am not quite sure what it is:

Let $K$ be a field and $f,g\in K[x,y]$ coprime. Then the greatest common divisor of $f$ and $g$ is a unit $u$ in $K$, which means that $u$ belongs to the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$, and therefore $(f,g)=K[x,y]$, which means that the algebraic variety $V(f,g)$ is empty.

I know that this conclusion must be false because there are instances of $f,g$ coprime with $V(f,g)$ not empty (finite yes, but not always empty). What fails in the argument above? I think I may have a wrong notion of what coprime means.

I would really appreciate if someone could point out why the argument is not valid. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: write out carefully what you mean each time you say the word "coprime". You will notice that you have two different statements there, and there's math that connects one to the other.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the greatest common divisor of two elements is not in the ideal generated by those elements. (This is true in a PID, though)

Consider the example of $x$ and $y$ inside $k[x,y]$. They are coprime, but if a linear combination $fx+gy=c$ is a constant, then evaluation at $(0,0)$ shows that this constant is zero.